# Sum the edge in adjacency matrix according to group label in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, igraph, numpy-ndarray, adjacency-matrix

For example, I got the symmetric adjacency matrix(no self-loop), i.e

```py
A = 
[
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Then, I got an array of cluster label i,  associated with this graph,  i.e

```py
cluster = [1,1,2,2,3]
```

It means that the node 1 and node 2 are in the same group, node 3 and node 4 are in the same group, node 5 are in a independent group.

The question is that how can I get the sum of the edges within groups and between groups,

Within groups: means the edge between nodes that share the same cluster label, for example, node 1 and node 2 are the in the same group, so the sum is 1 for them, the same for node 3 and node 4. For node 5, its 0.

Between groups: means the edge between nodes that share different cluster label,  for example, group 1 and group 2, it means that sum the edge of, node 1  node 3, node 1 node 4, node 2 node 3, node 2 node 4. The answer is 2 between group 1 and group 2.

then return a 2d symmetric array contains the result, i.e

```py
[[1,2,1],
[2,1,1],
[1,1,0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use matrix algebra;

```
cluster = np.array(cluster)
# create cluster-node adjacency matrix
aux = np.identity(cluster.max(),int)[cluster-1]
# we can now count by multiplying
out = aux.T@A@aux
# fix diagonal (which was counted twice)
np.einsum("ii->i",out)[...] //= 2
out
# array([[1, 2, 1],
#        [2, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 0]])
```

To speed this up we can replace the matrix product with
(1) if nodes are sorted by cluster:

```
boundaries = np.diff(cluster,prepend=-1).nonzero()[0]
out =  np.add.reduceat(np.add.reduceat(A,boundaries,1),boundaries,0)
```

(2) if not:

```
nc = cluster.max()
out = np.zeros((nc,nc),int)
np.add.at(out,(cluster[:,None]-1,cluster-1),A)
```

Comment: @NicolasH I added some comments, hope it helps.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Although, I would argue this is much slower (but more compact/readable) than the other method. I am curious if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @Ehsan, I guess so, yeah. One could try using sparse matrices. I'll try and write a faster hybrid version.

Answer (score 1):

This will return an array with element `[i,j]` the sum of edges of corresponding clusters `i` and `j`:

```
n = cluster.max()
degrees = np.zeros((n,n))
idx = [np.where(cluster==i)[0] for i in np.arange(n)+1]
for i in range(n):
  degrees[i,i] = A[np.ix_(idx[i],idx[i])].sum()/2
  for j in range(i):
    degrees[i,j] = degrees[j,i] = A[np.ix_(idx[i],idx[j])].sum()
```

output:

```
[[1. 2. 1.]
 [2. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0.]]
```

You can use itertools as well but I think this is probably faster.

Comment: @NicolasH You are welcome. I personally like Paul's answer as it is more abstract, but I would expect this to be faster (and more memory efficient) in case your graph is large enough/you care about performance.